# Android - Integer[] returning a number instead of String value

Tags: android, string, list, integer, adapter

I have a custom adapter and inside it this is my data source:

```
public Integer[] mList = {
        R.string.A,
        R.string.B,
        R.string.C,
        R.string.C,
        R.string.D,
        R.string.E,
        R.string.F,
        R.string.G,
};
```

When I set the TextView text like this:

```
mTextView.setText(mList[position]);
```

the value is whatever the String represents. But if I do this:

```
mTextView.setText(mList[position] + " Some Text");
```

The value is a 10 digit number. So it shows like this:

```
2126528311 Some Text
```

Why is this and how can I resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change line

```
mTextView.setText( getResources().getString(mList[position]) + " Some Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String array instead of integer array.

```
String[] list ={getResources().getString(R.string.a),
getResources().getString(R.string.b)};
```

Comment: Having changed that I get a null pointer exception! in the Activity thread which calls the Adapter. It doesn't pin point the line :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the text of your textview like this:

```
mTextView.setText(getResources().getString(mList[position]));
```

Comment: This worked for me. Creating String[] array gave unknown line null pointer exception